# HttpContext.Current.Session is reinitialized on redirecting to different URL of same ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC application and this web application is hosted on an IIS server with a traffic manager in front of it, so the application can be accessed by both the actual Web application URL(appweb1.test.com) and Traffic manager URL(app.test.com). If the end-user hits the Traffic manager URL the application redirects the request to the actual Web Application URL after Authentication is done and required Session variables are created.

The problem I am facing is that session variables set during authentication are lost when the application is accessed through the traffic manager URL (app.test.com) after redirecting to a different page of the same application but with a different URL (appweb1.test.com).

We are using a custom session state provider as Redis Cache, following <system.web> configuration is in web.config

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionStateStore">
      <providers>
        <add name="RedisSessionStateStore" type="NameSpace.SessionStateProvider" connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="15000" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="1000" databaseId="1" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
```

If the redirection is to the same URL then session keys are getting maintained.
I also checked that after redirection SessionId is changed, which means the session object is re-initialized, that is why all key values are lost.

Why session object is getting lost even though the application server is the same. Additionally, the Max worker Processes value is 1 for the application pool.

Comment: The answer may involve the code you're using to redirect. Can you include that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the HttpContext session object is created specific to URL, it does not matter whether the same server is getting pointed or not. So the same session object cannot be accessed on a different URL. I had to set the session object values on redirecting to new URL.